# Change color on active class when hover others li tag

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to change the `color` to `#000` on active class when hover others li tag

```
li:hover ~ li.active {
    color: #000
}
```

```css
li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
}

li.active {
    color: red;
}

li:hover {
    color: red;
}

/* How to do this */
li:hover ~ li.active {
    color: #000
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li class="active">Home</li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Hello</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

`~` (general sibling selector) selects **next** siblings.

It doesn't work in your example because `li.active` is the first item (a **previous** element) and can't be selected by `~ li.active`, so if you re-order your items to make `li.active` the last item, your code will work:

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Hello</li>
    <li class="active">Home</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Check out this famous [Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-selector) for tricks to select a previous sibling.

Comment: If you don't want to cheange the order of the items, you could easily solve it with JavaScript.

Comment: @MaazBhnas +1 from me great answer. However, you can reverse the order using just CSS. It is a bit hacky but it does the trick. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As @MoaazBhnas said, `~` (general sibling selector) selects the next siblings, so it won't work with this order. However, you can change the appearance of the order by using:

```css
ul {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
ul > li {
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
```

Then you can set your `nav` to `position: absolute;` and it will be in the initial position with your desired behavior.

```css
li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
}

li.active {
    color: red;
}

li:hover {
    color: red;
}

/* How to do this */
li:hover ~ li.active {
    color: #000
}

ul {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
ul > li {
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

nav {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>About</li>
    <li>Hello</li>
    <li class="active">Home</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```